WPF: make a control ignore DataContext of parent control
In my application, I have a data structure, and certain controls need to be bound to some of the properties in that structure, for example:
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Loading.Lcg.DisplayTitle}" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Loading.Lcg.Description}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Loading.Tcg.DisplayTitle}" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Loading.Tcg.Description}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Loading.Vcg.DisplayTitle}" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Loading.Vcg.Description}"/>
</StackPanel>

This results in very long markups, so I solved this by narrowing down the scope of the parent control DataContext, like this:
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Loading}">
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Lcg.DisplayTitle}" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Lcg.Description}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Tcg.DisplayTitle}" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Tcg.Description}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Vcg.DisplayTitle}" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Vcg.Description}"/>
</StackPanel>

However, I now need to introduce a new element inside the same StackPanel that is bound to a property a few steps "above" the parent DataContext, so I'd like to specify full path for that property while keeping others the same, like this:
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Loading}">
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Lcg.DisplayTitle}" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Lcg.Description}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Tcg.DisplayTitle}" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Tcg.Description}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Vcg.DisplayTitle}" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Vcg.Description}"/>
    
    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Options.TreatMassPropertiesAsIndependent}"/>
</StackPanel>

This, of course, fails, because CheckBox is searching for it's assigned property using the  DataContext of it's parent Stackpanel, rather than using the DataContext of the Page. Is there any way that I can make that CheckBox ignore the DataContext of the StackPanel, so I can specify the full path to the target property?
I attempted setting DataContext for that CheckBox explicitly (CheckBox DataContext="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate}", but it still starts searching for it from the StackPanel's DataContext. I can't find a way to make CheckBox's DataContext escape the influence of StackPanel.
P.S. I realize this code example seems like a bad design, and it appears simpler to just move the CheckBox outside the StackPanel, but this is heavily simplified code snippet, and there are good reasons for this kind of architecture in the real application.

Have you tried AncestorLevel & AncestorType

MS Learn / .NET / WPF / How to: Specify the Binding Source

For example, give the Page element a name and use Binding.ElementName to specify the source object. An implicit Binding always uses the current DataContext as source. If you want to use a different source you have to specify the binding source explicitly.

you can use nested panels:
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Loading}">
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Lcg.DisplayTitle}" 
               ToolTip="{Binding Path=Lcg.Description}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Tcg.DisplayTitle}" 
               ToolTip="{Binding Path=Tcg.Description}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Vcg.DisplayTitle}" 
               ToolTip="{Binding Path=Vcg.Description}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=ConditionInputDataTemplate.Vessel.Options.TreatMassPropertiesAsIndependent}"/>
</StackPanel>

